# Bootstrap 3 move position of divs on mobile

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, media-queries

So according to this: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid-column-ordering I should be able to swap the position of the divs based on the viewport.

I tried with the following html (it is twig - but that shouldn't make a difference):

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-xs-push-12" id="recommend-container">
                    <h1>
                        <i class="fas fa-chess-king"></i>
                        Solomon
                    </h1>

                    <hr />

                    <div id="recommend-contents">
                        <p>Solomon Recommends:</p>

                        {% for type,recommend in recommendations %}
                            <h3>{{ type }}</h3>

                            <ul>
                                {% for index,name in recommend %}
                                    <li>{{ name }}</li>
                                {% endfor %}
                            </ul>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-xs-pull-12" id="register-section-container">
                    <h1>Register</h1>
                    <hr />

                    {{ form_start(form) }}
                        {{ form_row(form.username, { 'attr': {'class': 'form-control login-input', 'placeholder': 'username'} }) }}
                        {{ form_row(form.email, { 'attr': {'class': 'form-control login-input', 'placeholder': 'email'} }) }}
                        {{ form_row(form.plainPassword.first, { 'attr': {'class': 'form-control login-input', 'placeholder': 'password'} }) }}
                        {{ form_row(form.plainPassword.second, { 'attr': {'class': 'form-control login-input', 'placeholder': 'retype password'} }) }}

                        <div class="register-btn-container">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary d-inline-block" type="submit">
                                <i class="fas fa-check"></i>
                                Register
                            </button>

                            <p class="d-inline-block">Already signed up? <a href="/login">Login</a></p>
                        </div>
                    {{ form_end(form) }}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

which not only doesn't work on mobile, but creates a weird space between the divs on desktop view? I really don't understand the logic of it, how do I debug or fix? (CSS is the real Isildur's bane)

Comment: You need to add an [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example so we can help you.

Comment: @GerardoBLANCO your way of asking for css? :)

Comment: I would love helping you, but cant debug or fix with the current information.

Comment: @GerardoBLANCO but I'm using the generic bootstrap class, the doc says what I used should work.. yet it doesn't and pushes my content out of it's parent .. CSS is the only thing I can think of that would alter default behaviour of Bootstrap so if you think adding the css applied by my main.css file for these elements than I can?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you issue is du to the fact that Bootstrap is a mobile first framework, and you try to use it as a desktop first one.

You should place divs the way you want them to be displayed on a mobile, THEN pull/push them on larger screen :

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous"> 
 
 <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <!-- LEFT ON DESKTOP -->
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-sm-push-6" id="recommend-container">
        I'm on the right on desktop
        </div>
        <!-- RIGHT ON DESKTOP -->
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-sm-pull-6" id="register-section-container">
        I'm on the left on desktop
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Here is that will append:**

on mobile devices (viewport under 768px width): the `.col-xs-12` rule apply so divs should be display on top of each other in the same order as the code.

Then when you reach 768px width (and up): the `.col-sm-6` rule apply so you should have the two columns displayed side by side as each column is set to occupy 1/2 of the available space (6/12 to be exact :)).
And as you want to "inverse" the "logical" order of the columns, you add one rule to push the first column on the right (`.col-sm-pull-6`), and one rule to pull the second column on the left (`.col-sm-pull-6`).

As long as you don't have rules specific to superior width (aka: "md" and "lg"), the "sm" rule will be used on larger screens.

Comment: See media query not as isolated rules but as a rules that modify previous one. So first you have all the rules outside of any media query that applies, then the ones corresponding to "xs" MODIFIES previous rules, then "sm" MODIFIES (including "xs") previous rules etc, etc...

Comment: I don't get it, if you only want to target mobile , you don't need to use other rules than the "xs" ones. That are you trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: Ok, I updated/completed my answer, hope it's clearer.

Comment: The last point on the grid system intriduction is relatively explicite : Grid classes apply to devices with screen widths greater than or equal to the breakpoint sizes, and override grid classes targeted at smaller devices. Therefore, e.g. applying any .col-md-* class to an element will not only affect its styling on medium devices but also on large devices if a .col-lg-* class is not present.

Comment: Becasue "md" rules are for 992px and up. usually a mobile is under 768px, except for device with a retina screen (x2 on the pixels count I believe).

Comment: Yes you have to think from mobile to desktop, it take some practice but once you get it, it will make sense.

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep at it, frontend has never been my area of expertise but hopefully with more time I can make it a skill :) thanks again1